# What is Symfony 2's @Assert\Email validation criteria for a valid email?

Tags: validation, email, symfony

I'm running into a problem where the following email `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanom@domaine.com` is not valid according to this assertion on the Doctrine Entity using `@Assert\Email` for the `email` property.

I don't see any documentation detailing what the checks are for passing or failing this validation.

Curious to know where the code is or where I can find more documentation on what this assertion is doing...

#### Update, my whole assertions on that Entity property are:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=511)
     * @Filter\Trim()
     * @Filter\StripNewlines()
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="email.error")
     * @Assert\Email(message="email.error")
     * @Assert\Length(min="6", max="150", minMessage="email.error", maxMessage="email.error")
     * @Encrypted
     */
    private $email;
```

Using Symfony 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony 2.3 [Email validator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/EmailValidator.php#L39) uses the PHP var filter method

```
$valid = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Which the [internet](https://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) leads em to believe uses similar to the following (ridiculous) regex (broken into multiple lines for readability)

```
^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?
\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\
x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\
x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\
x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:
\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]
+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[
(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(
?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)
))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(
?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?
)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])
|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$
```

So make of that what you will.

In short, the local part of the email address is too long.
I'm not sure which part of regex decides that though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EmailValidator` class is what you're looking for. Check [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/EmailValidator.php)

Comment: Correct. Today the regex used by Symfony for email is : '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+$'